# Como utilizar a classe Scanner para ler dois inputs separados por um espaço em Java, e por em duas variáveis distintas?

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer algo simples, eu gostaria que, dado dois argumentos separados por um espaço, lidos através do stdin, cada um seja armazenado em uma variável diferente, por exemplo:

```
 Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in)

 Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in)

 input1 = s1.nextLine();

 input2 = s2.nextLine();

 a = input1 

 b = input2
```

E o usuário escreve no System.in, por exemplo:

```
> Up Down
```

No código que dei como exemplo input1 e input2 estão sempre lendo as mesmas coisas, preciso que um leia só o primeiro argumento e o outro só o segundo argumento.

Considerando o exemplo, como eu faço para que a variável `a` receba apenas a string *Up*, e a variável `b` receba apenas a string *Down*?

Comment: Não precisa criar dois scanners se eles lêem do mesmo lugar (no caso, do `System.in`). Use um só que é suficiente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar um scanner só e aplicar `split(" ")` à String retornada por ele:

```
input = s1.nextLine();
String [] palavras = input.split(" ");
for (String palavra : palavras) {
    System.out.println(palavra);
}

String comando = palavras[0];
```